# SharePoint 2013 Apps installation is taking a very long time

Tags: sharepoint-addin

All said: almost 10' to install an app.

...
  Installation is in progress (00:09:40)
  Installation is in progress (00:09:45)
  Installation is in progress (00:09:51)
  App was installed at http://apps-f0c7be441dae86.corp.contosoapps.com/sites/blank/SampleApp/.

Any hints? Gonna investigate soon, but wanted to check if there's a silver bullet in the meantime. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no silver bullet ever, you should know that by now! :) Well, my advise would be to try taking the app apart piece by piece and deploy it after each removed piece so that you can find the piece causing that. For example I had some nasty experience with a completely misleading error message like "Sorry server is not available" or something like that because of a mistake in ClientWebPart manifest... It's SharePoint, man! :)

Comment: Hmmm this repros with the simplest app I build from the OOB templates, it's not related to the app per-se.

Comment: Well, in this case... Did you check your "App Installation Service" timer job? Not only settings, but also logs: how often does it run actually? AFAIKR it should run every 5 mins by default.

Comment: Correct, running every 5'.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if the SharePoint Timer Service is running fine.